# What are the best Indexes for a frequently changing table?

Tags: sql-server

I work on databases used for Analysis workloads so I usually use a stored procedure to output final datasets into SQL Server tables that we can connect to from Tableau or SAS, etc.

We process multiple batches of data through the same system so the output dataset tables all contain a BATCH_ID column which users use to filter on the specific batch they want to analyze.

Each time a dataset is published, I delete any old data for that batch in the output table before inserting a fresh set of rows for that batch of data.  For this type of workload what do you think the best indexes would be?

I'm currently using a clustered index on the `BATCH_ID` column because I figured that would group all the rows together resulting in efficient filtering and deletion/insertion. Will this result in a lot of index or table fragmentation over time?  Keep in mind that the entire batch is deleted and re-inserted each time so there's no issue with partial updates or additions to existing batches.

Would I be better off with a typical clustered index on an identity column and a non-clustered index on `batch_ID`?

Comment: Not bad.  If the clustered index is not unique I think SQLdoes some stuff to make it unique under the cover but not a reason not to use it that way as far as I know.  It the insert is all one BATCH_ID it will not fragment much.  It the insert is multiple BATCH_ID then sort the insert first if you can.